# Bit vector in Java supporting O(1) rank() and O(log n) select()

Tags: java, algorithm, bitwise, vectors, bitset

## Introduction

I have [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/coderodde/RankSelectBitVector.java/tree/1aaa9c6da6641528bcbe6be13506a073d85d7113) (version 1.0.0.). It implements a `rank(i)` operation in \$\Theta(1)\$ time, and `select(i)` operation in \$\Theta(\log n)\$ time.

(This post has an [continuation post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289221/bit-vector-in-java-supporting-o1-rank-and-olog-n-select-follow-up), version 1.0.1.)

## Code

**`com.github.coderodde.util.RankSelectBitVector.java:`**

```
/**
 * This class defines a packed bit vector that supports {@code rank()} operation
 * in {@code O(1)} time, and {@code select()} in {@code O(log n)} time.
 * 
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
public final class RankSelectBitVector {
    
    /**
     * Indicates whether some bits were changed since the previous building of
     * the index data structures.
     */
    private boolean hasDirtyState = true;
    
    /**
     * The actual bit storage array.
     */
    private final byte[] bytes;
    
    /**
     * The actual requested number of bits in this bit vector. Will be smaller 
     * than the total capacity.
     */
    private final int numberOfRequestedBits;
    
    /**
     * Denotes index of the most rightmost meaningful bit. Will be set to 
     * {@code numberOfRequestedBits - 1}.
     */
    private final int maximumBitIndex;
    
    /**
     * Caches the number of bits set to one (1).
     */
    private int numberOfSetBits;
    
    /**
     * The block size in the {@code first} table.
     */
    private int ell;
    
    /**
     * The block size in the {@code second} table.
     */
    private int k;
    
    // The following three tables hold the index necessary for efficient rank 
    // operation. According to internet, has space 
    // O(sgrt(n) * log log n * log n.
    private int[] first;
    private int[] second;
    private int[][] third;
    
    /**
     * Constructs a new bit vector.
     * 
     * @param numberOfRequestedBits the actual number of bits to support.
     */
    public RankSelectBitVector(int numberOfRequestedBits) {
        checkNumberOfRequestedBits(numberOfRequestedBits);
        
        this.numberOfRequestedBits = numberOfRequestedBits;
        
        // Calculate the actual number of storage bytes:
        int numberOfBytes = numberOfRequestedBits / Byte.SIZE + 
                           (numberOfRequestedBits % Byte.SIZE != 0 ? 1 : 0);
        
        numberOfBytes++; // Padding tail byte in order to simplify the last 
                         // rank/select.
        
        bytes = new byte[numberOfBytes];
        
        // Set the rightmost, valid index:
        this.maximumBitIndex = this.bytes.length * Byte.SIZE - 1;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append("[Bit vector, size = ");
        
        sb.append(getNumberOfSupportedBits())
          .append(" bits, data = ");
        
        int bitNumber = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < getNumberOfSupportedBits(); i++) {
            sb.append(readBitImpl(i) ? "1" : "0");
            
            bitNumber++;
            
            if (bitNumber % 8 == 0) {
                sb.append(" ");
            }
        }
        
        return sb.append("]").toString();
    }
    
    /**
     * Preprocesses the internal data structures in {@code O(n)}.
     */
    public void buildIndices() {
        if (hasDirtyState == false) {
            // Nothing to do.
            return;
        }
        
        //// Deal with the 'first'.
        // n - total number of bit slots:
        int n = bytes.length * Byte.SIZE;
        
        // elll - the l value:
        this.ell = (int) Math.pow(Math.ceil(log2(n) / 2.0), 2.0);
        this.first = new int[n / ell + 1];
        
        for (int i = ell; i < n; i++) {
            if (i % ell == 0) {
                int firstArraySlotIndex = i / ell;
                int startIndex = i - ell;
                int endIndex   = i - 1;
                
                first[firstArraySlotIndex]     =
                first[firstArraySlotIndex - 1] + 
                bruteForceRank(startIndex,
                               endIndex);
            }
        }
        
        //// Deal with the 'second'.
        this.k = (int) Math.ceil(log2(n) / 2.0);
        this.second = new int[n / k + 1];
        
        for (int i = k; i < n; i++) {
            if (i % k == 0) {
                second[i/k] = bruteForceRank(ell * (i / ell), i - 1);
            }
        }
        
        //// Deal with the 'third': four Russians' technique:
        this.third = new int[(int) Math.pow(2.0, k - 1)][];
        
        for (int selectorIndex = 0;
                 selectorIndex < third.length;
                 selectorIndex++) {
            
            third[selectorIndex] = new int[k - 1];
            
            // third[selectorIndex][0] is always zero (0).
            third[selectorIndex][0] = (bitIsSet(selectorIndex, k - 2) ? 1 : 0);
            
            for (int j = 1; j < k - 1; j++) {
                third[selectorIndex][j] = 
                third[selectorIndex][j - 1] + 
                        (bitIsSet(selectorIndex, k - j - 2) ? 1 : 0);
            }
        }
        
        hasDirtyState = false;
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the number of bits that are set (have value of one (1)).
     * 
     * @return the number of set bits.
     */
    public int getNumberOfSetBits() {
        return numberOfSetBits;
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the number of bits this bit vector supports.
     * 
     * @return the number of bits supported.
     */
    public int getNumberOfSupportedBits() {
        return numberOfRequestedBits;
    }
    
    /**
     * Sets the {@code index}th bit to one (1).
     * 
     * @param index the index of the target bit.
     */
    public void writeBitOn(int index) {
        writeBit(index, true);
    }
    
    /**
     * Sets the {@code index}th bit to zero (0).
     * 
     * @param index the index of the target bit.
     */
    public void writeBitOff(int index) {
        writeBit(index, false);
    }
    
    /**
     * Writes the {@code index}th bit to {@code on}.
     * 
     * @param index the index of the target bit.
     * @param on    the selector of the bit: if {@code true}, the bit will be 
     *              set to one, otherwise set zero.
     */
    public void writeBit(int index, boolean on) {
        checkBitAccessIndex(index);
        writeBitImpl(index, on);
    }
    
    /**
     * Reads the {@code index}th bit where indexation starts from zero (0).
     * 
     * @param index the bit index.
     * @return {@code true} if and only if the {@code index}th bit is set.
     */
    public boolean readBit(int index) {
        checkBitAccessIndex(index);
        return readBitImpl(index);
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the rank of {@code index}, i.e., the number of set bits in the 
     * subvector {@code vector[1..index]}. Runs in {@code O((log n)^2)} time.
     * 
     * @param index the target index.
     * @return the rank for the input target.
     */
    public int rankFirst(int index) {
        checkBitIndexForRank(index);
        makeSureStateIsCompiled();
        
        int startIndex = ell * (index / ell);
        int endIndex = index - 1;
        
        return first[index / ell] + bruteForceRank(startIndex, endIndex);
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the {@code index}th rank. Runs in {@code O(log n)} time.
     * 
     * @param index the target index.
     * @return the rank of the input index.
     */
    public int rankSecond(int index) {
        checkBitIndexForRank(index);
        makeSureStateIsCompiled();
        
        int startIndex = k * (index / k);
        int endIndex = index - 1;
        
        return first[index / ell] +
               second[index / k] + 
               bruteForceRank(startIndex, 
                              endIndex);
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the {@code index}th rank. Runs in {@code O(1)} time.
     * 
     * @param index the target index.
     * @return the rank of the input index.
     */
    public int rankThird(int index) {
        checkBitIndexForRank(index);
        makeSureStateIsCompiled();
        
        int f = first[index / ell];
        int s = second[index / k];
        
        int thirdEntryIndex = index % k - 1;
        
        if (thirdEntryIndex == -1) {
            return f + s;
        }
        
        int selectorIndex = 
                extractBitVector(index)
                        .toInteger(k - 1);
        
        return f + s + third[selectorIndex][thirdEntryIndex];
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the index of the {@code index}th 1-bit. Relies on 
     * {@link #rankFirst(int)}, which runs in {@code O((log n)^2)}, which yields
     * {@code O((log n)^3)} running time for the {@code selectFirst}.
     * 
     * @param bitIndex the target index.
     * @return the index of the {@code index}th 1-bit.
     */
    public int selectFirst(int bitIndex) {
        checkBitIndexForSelect(bitIndex);
        return selectImplFirst(bitIndex, 0, getNumberOfSupportedBits());
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the index of the {@code index}th 1-bit. Relies on 
     * {@link #rankSecond(int)}, which runs in {@code O(log n)}, which yields
     * {@code O((log n)^2)} running time for the {@code selectSecond}.
     * 
     * @param bitIndex the target index.
     * @return the index of the {@code index}th 1-bit.
     */
    public int selectSecond(int bitIndex) {
        checkBitIndexForSelect(bitIndex);
        return selectImplSecond(bitIndex, 0, getNumberOfSupportedBits());
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the index of the {@code index}th 1-bit. Relies on 
     * {@link #rankThird(int)}, which runs in {@code O(1)}, which yields
     * {@code O(log n)} running time for the {@code selectThird}.
     * 
     * @param bitIndex the target index.
     * @return the index of the {@code index}th 1-bit.
     */
    public int selectThird(int bitIndex) {
        checkBitIndexForSelect(bitIndex);
        return selectImplThird(bitIndex, 0, getNumberOfSupportedBits());
    }
    
    private int selectImplFirst(int bitIndex,
                                int rangeStartIndex,
                                int rangeLength) {
        
        if (rangeLength == 1) {
            return rangeStartIndex;
        }
        
        int halfRangeLength = rangeLength / 2;
        int r = rankFirst(halfRangeLength + rangeStartIndex);
        
        if (r >= bitIndex) {
            return selectImplFirst(bitIndex, 
                              rangeStartIndex,
                              halfRangeLength);
        } else {
            return selectImplFirst(bitIndex, 
                              rangeStartIndex + halfRangeLength,
                              rangeLength - halfRangeLength);
        }
    }
    
    private int selectImplSecond(int bitIndex, 
                                 int rangeStartIndex,
                                 int rangeLength) {
        
        if (rangeLength == 1) {
            return rangeStartIndex;
        }
        
        int halfRangeLength = rangeLength / 2;
        int r = rankSecond(halfRangeLength + rangeStartIndex);
        
        if (r >= bitIndex) {
            return selectImplSecond(bitIndex, 
                                    rangeStartIndex,
                                    halfRangeLength);
        } else {
            return selectImplSecond(bitIndex, 
                                    rangeStartIndex + halfRangeLength,
                                    rangeLength - halfRangeLength);
        }
    }
    
    private int selectImplThird(int bitIndex,
                                int rangeStartIndex, 
                                int rangeLength) {
        
        if (rangeLength == 1) {
            return rangeStartIndex;
        }
        
        int halfRangeLength = rangeLength / 2;
        int r = rankThird(halfRangeLength + rangeStartIndex);
        
        if (r >= bitIndex) {
            return selectImplThird(bitIndex, 
                                   rangeStartIndex,
                                   halfRangeLength);
        } else {
            return selectImplThird(bitIndex, 
                                   rangeStartIndex + halfRangeLength,
                                   rangeLength - halfRangeLength);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * The delegate for manipulating bits.
     * 
     * @param index the index of the target bit.
     * @param on    the flag deciding the value of the bit in question.
     */
    private void writeBitImpl(int index, boolean on) {
        boolean previousBitValue = readBit(index);
        
        if (on) {
            if (previousBitValue == false) {
                hasDirtyState = true;
                numberOfSetBits++;
            }
            
            turnBitOn(index);
        } else {
            if (previousBitValue == true) {
                hasDirtyState = true;
                numberOfSetBits--;
            }
            
            turnBitOff(index);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Implements the actual reading of a bit.
     * 
     * @param index the index of the target bit to read.
     * @return the value of the target bit.
     */
    boolean readBitImpl(int index) {
        int byteIndex = index / Byte.SIZE;
        int targetByteBitIndex = index % Byte.SIZE;
        byte targetByte = bytes[byteIndex];
        return (targetByte & (1 << targetByteBitIndex)) != 0;
    }
    
    /**
     * Makes sure that the state of the internal data structures is up to date.
     */
    private void makeSureStateIsCompiled() {
        if (hasDirtyState) {
            buildIndices();
            hasDirtyState = false;
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Turns the {@code index}th bit on. Indexation is zero-based.
     * 
     * @param index the target bit index.
     */
    private void turnBitOn(int index) {
        int byteIndex = index / Byte.SIZE;
        int bitIndex = index % Byte.SIZE;
        byte mask = 1;
        mask <<= bitIndex;
        bytes[byteIndex] |= mask;
    }
    
    /**
     * Turns the {@code index}th bit off. Indexation is zero-based.
     * 
     * @param index the target bit index.
     */
    private void turnBitOff(int index) {
        int byteIndex = index / Byte.SIZE;
        int bitIndex = index % Byte.SIZE;
        byte mask = 1;
        mask <<= bitIndex;
        bytes[byteIndex] &= ~mask;
    }
    
    private void checkBitIndexForSelect(int selectionIndex) {
        if (selectionIndex < 0) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    String.format(
                            "The input selection index is negative: " + 
                            "(%d). Must be within range [1..%d].\n",
                            selectionIndex,
                            numberOfSetBits));
        }
        
        if (selectionIndex == 0) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    String.format(
                            "The input selection index is zero (0). " + 
                            "Must be within range [1..%d].\n",
                            numberOfSetBits));
        }
        
        if (selectionIndex > numberOfSetBits) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    String.format(
                            "The input selection index is too large (%d). " + 
                            "Must be within range [1..%d].\n", 
                            selectionIndex, 
                            numberOfSetBits));
        }
    }
    
    private void checkBitIndexForRank(int index) {
        if (index < 0) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    String.format("Negative bit index: %d.", index));
        } 
        
        if (index > numberOfRequestedBits) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    String.format(
                            "Too large bit index (%d), number of bits " + 
                            "supported is %d.",
                            index, 
                            numberOfRequestedBits));
        }
    }
    
    private void checkBitAccessIndex(int accessIndex) {
        if (accessIndex < 0) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    String.format(
                            "Negative bit access index: %d.",
                            accessIndex));
        } 
        
        if (accessIndex >= getNumberOfSupportedBits()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    String.format(
                            "Too large bit access index (%d), number of bits " + 
                            "supported is %d.",
                            accessIndex, 
                            getNumberOfSupportedBits()));
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns {@code true} if and only if the {@code bitIndex}th bit in 
     * {@code value} is set.
     * 
     * @param value    the value of which to inspect the bit.
     * @param bitIndex the bit index.
     * @return {@code true} if and only if the specified bit is set.
     */
    private boolean bitIsSet(int value, int bitIndex) {
        return (value & (1 << bitIndex)) != 0;
    }
    
    int toInteger(int numberOfBitsToRead) {
        int integer = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBitsToRead; i++) {
            
            boolean bit = readBitImpl(i);
            
            if (bit == true) {
                integer |= 1 << i;
            }
        }
        
        return integer;
    }
    
    private RankSelectBitVector extractBitVector(int i) {
        int startIndex = k * (i / k);
        int endIndex = Math.min(k * (i / k + 1) - 2, maximumBitIndex);
        
        int extractedBitVectorLength = endIndex - startIndex + 1;
        
        RankSelectBitVector extractedBitVector = 
                new RankSelectBitVector(extractedBitVectorLength);
        
        for (int index = extractedBitVectorLength - 1,
                j = startIndex; 
                j <= endIndex;
                j++, index--) {
            
            extractedBitVector.writeBitImpl(index, this.readBitImpl(j));
        }
        
        return extractedBitVector;
    }
    
    private int bruteForceRank(int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        int rank = 0; 
        
        for (int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
            if (readBitImpl(i)) {
                rank++;
            }
        }
        
        return rank;
    }
    
    private void checkNumberOfRequestedBits(int numberOfRequestedBits) {
        if (numberOfRequestedBits == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Requested zero (0) bits.");
        }
        
        if (numberOfRequestedBits < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    String.format(
                            "Requested negative number of bits (%d).\n", 
                            numberOfRequestedBits));
        }
    }
    
    private static double log2(double v) {
        return Math.log(v) / Math.log(2.0);
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.util.RankSelectBitVectorBenchmark.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util.benchmark;

import com.github.coderodde.util.RankSelectBitVector;
import java.util.Random;

public final class RankSelectBitVectorBenchmark {
    
    /**
     * The number of bits in the benchmark bit vector.
     */
    private static final int BIT_VECTOR_LENGTH = 4_000_000;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long seed = parseSeed(args);
        
        System.out.printf("Seed = %d\n", seed);
        Random random = new Random(seed);
        
        long st = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        RankSelectBitVector rankSelectBitVector = createRandomBitVector(random);
        
        System.out.printf("Built the bit vector in %d milliseconds.\n",
                          System.currentTimeMillis() - st);
        
        st = System.currentTimeMillis(); // st - start time.
        
        rankSelectBitVector.buildIndices();
        
        System.out.printf("Preprocessed the bit vector in %d milliseconds.\n",
                          System.currentTimeMillis() - st);
        
        System.out.println("--- Benchmarking rank operation ---");
        
        benchmarkRanks(rankSelectBitVector);
        
        System.out.println("--- Benchmarking select operation ---");
        
        benchmarkSelects(rankSelectBitVector);
    }
    
    private static RankSelectBitVector createRandomBitVector(Random random) {
        RankSelectBitVector rankSelectBitVector =
                new RankSelectBitVector(BIT_VECTOR_LENGTH);
        
        for (int bitIndex = 0;
                bitIndex != rankSelectBitVector.getNumberOfSupportedBits(); 
                bitIndex++) {
            
            if (random.nextBoolean()) {
                rankSelectBitVector.writeBitOn(bitIndex);
            }
        }
        
        return rankSelectBitVector;
    }
    
    private static boolean rankArraysEqual(int[] rankArray1, int[] rankArray2) {
        if (rankArray1.length != rankArray2.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Rank array length mismatch.");
        }
        
        int n = Math.max(rankArray1.length, rankArray2.length);
        
        for (int i = 0; i != n; i++) {
            int rank1 = rankArray1[i];
            int rank2 = rankArray2[i];
            
            if (rank1 != rank2) {
                System.err.printf(
                        "ERROR: Mismatch at index = %d, " + 
                        "rank1 = %d, rank2 = %d.\n",
                        i,
                        rank1,
                        rank2);
                
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        return true;
    }
    
    private static void
         benchmarkRanks(RankSelectBitVector rankSelectBitVector) {
        
        int numberOfBits = rankSelectBitVector.getNumberOfSupportedBits();
        
        int[] answers1 = new int[numberOfBits];
        int[] answers2 = new int[numberOfBits];
        int[] answers3 = new int[numberOfBits];
        
        long st = System.currentTimeMillis(); // st - start time.
        
        for (int i = 0; i != numberOfBits; i++) {
            answers1[i] = rankSelectBitVector.rankFirst(i);
        }
        
        long answersDuration1 = System.currentTimeMillis() - st;
        
        System.out.printf(
                "rankFirst() ran for %d milliseconds.\n", 
                answersDuration1);
        
        st = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        for (int i = 0; i != numberOfBits; i++) {
            answers2[i] = rankSelectBitVector.rankSecond(i);
        }
        
        long answersDuration2 = System.currentTimeMillis() - st;
        
        System.out.printf(
                "rankSecond() ran for %d milliseconds.\n",
                answersDuration2);
        
        st = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        for (int i = 0; i != numberOfBits; i++) {
            answers3[i] = rankSelectBitVector.rankThird(i);
        }
        
        long answersDuration3 = System.currentTimeMillis() - st;
        
        System.out.printf(
                "rankThird() ran for %d milliseconds.\n",
                answersDuration3);
        
        if (!rankArraysEqual(answers1, answers2)) {
            System.err.println("Failed on rankFirst vs. rankSecond.");
            return;
        }
        
        if (!rankArraysEqual(answers1, answers3)) {
            System.err.println("Failed on rankFirst vs. rankThird.");
        }
    }
         
    private static void
         benchmarkSelects(RankSelectBitVector rankSelectBitVector) {
        int numberOfSetBits = rankSelectBitVector.getNumberOfSetBits();
        
        int[] answers1 = new int[numberOfSetBits + 1];
        int[] answers2 = new int[numberOfSetBits + 1];
        int[] answers3 = new int[numberOfSetBits + 1];
        
        long st = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfSetBits; i++) {
            answers1[i] = rankSelectBitVector.selectFirst(i);
        }
        
        long answersDuration1 = System.currentTimeMillis() - st;
        
        System.out.printf(
                "selectFirst() ran for %d milliseconds.\n", 
                answersDuration1);
        
        st = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfSetBits; i++) {
            answers2[i] = rankSelectBitVector.selectSecond(i);
        }
        
        long answersDuration2 = System.currentTimeMillis() - st;
        
        System.out.printf(
                "selectSecond() ran for %d milliseconds.\n",
                answersDuration2);
        
        st = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfSetBits; i++) {
            answers3[i] = rankSelectBitVector.selectThird(i);
        }
        
        long answersDuration3 = System.currentTimeMillis() - st;
        
        System.out.printf(
                "selectThird() ran for %d milliseconds.\n",
                answersDuration3);
        
        if (!rankArraysEqual(answers1, answers2)) {
            System.err.println("Failed on selectFirst vs. selectSecond.");
            return;
        }
        
        if (!rankArraysEqual(answers1, answers3)) {
            System.err.println("Failed on selectFirst vs. selectThird.");
        }
    }
         
    private static long parseSeed(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            return System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        
        try {
            return Long.parseLong(args[0]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.err.printf(
                    "WARNING: Could not parse '%s' as an long value.", args[0]);
            
            return System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.util.RankSelectBitVectorTest.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Random;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import org.junit.Test;

public final class RankSelectBitVectorTest {
    
    @Test
    public void lastBitRank() {
        RankSelectBitVector bv = new RankSelectBitVector(8);
        
        bv.writeBitOn(2);
        bv.writeBitOn(6);
        bv.writeBitOn(7);
        
        assertEquals(3, bv.rankFirst(8));
        assertEquals(3, bv.rankSecond(8));
        assertEquals(3, bv.rankThird(8));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void smallSelect() {
        RankSelectBitVector bv = new RankSelectBitVector(8);
        
        bv.writeBitOn(2);
        bv.writeBitOn(4);
        bv.writeBitOn(5);
        bv.writeBitOn(7);
        
        // 00101101
        // select(1) = 2
        // select(2) = 4
        // select(3) = 5
        // select(4) = 7
        
        assertEquals(2, bv.selectFirst(1));
        assertEquals(4, bv.selectFirst(2));
        assertEquals(5, bv.selectFirst(3));
        assertEquals(7, bv.selectFirst(4));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void debugTest1() {
        // 00101101
        RankSelectBitVector bv = new RankSelectBitVector(8);
        
        bv.writeBitOn(2);
        bv.writeBitOn(4);
        bv.writeBitOn(5);
        bv.writeBitOn(7);
        
        assertEquals(0, bv.rankThird(0));
        assertEquals(0, bv.rankThird(1));
        assertEquals(0, bv.rankThird(2));
        assertEquals(1, bv.rankThird(3));
        assertEquals(1, bv.rankThird(4));
        assertEquals(2, bv.rankThird(5));
        assertEquals(3, bv.rankThird(6));
        assertEquals(3, bv.rankThird(7));
        assertEquals(4, bv.rankThird(8));
        
        assertEquals(2, bv.selectFirst(1));
        assertEquals(4, bv.selectFirst(2));
        assertEquals(5, bv.selectFirst(3));
        assertEquals(7, bv.selectFirst(4));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void debugTest2() {
        // 00101101 10101101
        RankSelectBitVector bv = new RankSelectBitVector(16);
        
        bv.writeBitOn(2);
        bv.writeBitOn(4);
        bv.writeBitOn(5);
        bv.writeBitOn(7);
        
        bv.writeBitOn(8);
        bv.writeBitOn(10);
        bv.writeBitOn(12);
        bv.writeBitOn(13);
        bv.writeBitOn(15);
        
        assertEquals(0, bv.rankThird(0));
        assertEquals(0, bv.rankThird(1));
        assertEquals(0, bv.rankThird(2));
        assertEquals(1, bv.rankThird(3));
        assertEquals(1, bv.rankThird(4));
        assertEquals(2, bv.rankThird(5));
        assertEquals(3, bv.rankThird(6));
        assertEquals(3, bv.rankThird(7));
        assertEquals(4, bv.rankThird(8));
        
        assertEquals(5, bv.rankThird(9));
        assertEquals(5, bv.rankThird(10));
        assertEquals(6, bv.rankThird(11));
        assertEquals(6, bv.rankThird(12));
        assertEquals(7, bv.rankThird(13));
        assertEquals(8, bv.rankThird(14));
        assertEquals(8, bv.rankThird(15));
        assertEquals(9, bv.rankThird(16));
        
        assertEquals(2, bv.selectFirst(1));
        assertEquals(4, bv.selectFirst(2));
        assertEquals(5, bv.selectFirst(3));
        assertEquals(7, bv.selectFirst(4));
        
        assertEquals(8, bv.selectFirst(5));
        assertEquals(10, bv.selectFirst(6));
        assertEquals(12, bv.selectFirst(7));
        assertEquals(13, bv.selectFirst(8));
        assertEquals(15, bv.selectFirst(9));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void debugTest3() {
        // 00101101 10101101 00010010
        RankSelectBitVector bv = new RankSelectBitVector(24);
        
        bv.writeBitOn(2);
        bv.writeBitOn(4);
        bv.writeBitOn(5);
        bv.writeBitOn(7);
        
        bv.writeBitOn(8);
        bv.writeBitOn(10);
        bv.writeBitOn(12);
        bv.writeBitOn(13);
        bv.writeBitOn(15);
        
        bv.writeBitOn(19);
        bv.writeBitOn(22);
        
        assertEquals(0, bv.rankThird(0));
        assertEquals(0, bv.rankThird(1));
        assertEquals(0, bv.rankThird(2));
        assertEquals(1, bv.rankThird(3));
        assertEquals(1, bv.rankThird(4));
        assertEquals(2, bv.rankThird(5));
        assertEquals(3, bv.rankThird(6));
        assertEquals(3, bv.rankThird(7));
        assertEquals(4, bv.rankThird(8));
        
        assertEquals(5, bv.rankThird(9));
        assertEquals(5, bv.rankThird(10));
        assertEquals(6, bv.rankThird(11));
        assertEquals(6, bv.rankThird(12));
        assertEquals(7, bv.rankThird(13));
        assertEquals(8, bv.rankThird(14));
        assertEquals(8, bv.rankThird(15));
        assertEquals(9, bv.rankThird(16));
        
        // 00010010
        assertEquals(9, bv.rankThird(17));
        assertEquals(9, bv.rankThird(18));
        assertEquals(9, bv.rankThird(19));
        assertEquals(10, bv.rankThird(20));
        assertEquals(10, bv.rankThird(21));
        assertEquals(10, bv.rankThird(22));
        assertEquals(11, bv.rankThird(23));
        assertEquals(11, bv.rankThird(24));
        
        // select():
        assertEquals(2, bv.selectFirst(1));
        assertEquals(4, bv.selectFirst(2));
        assertEquals(5, bv.selectFirst(3));
        assertEquals(7, bv.selectFirst(4));
        
        assertEquals(8, bv.selectFirst(5));
        assertEquals(10, bv.selectFirst(6));
        assertEquals(12, bv.selectFirst(7));
        assertEquals(13, bv.selectFirst(8));
        assertEquals(15, bv.selectFirst(9));
        
        assertEquals(19, bv.selectFirst(10));
        assertEquals(22, bv.selectFirst(11));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void bruteForceTest() {
        long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        seed = 1706163778488L;
        Random random = new Random(seed);
        System.out.println("-- bruteForceTest, seed = " + seed);
        
        RankSelectBitVector bv = getRandomBitVector(random);
        BruteForceBitVector referenceBv = copy(bv);
        
        bv.buildIndices();
       
        int numberOfOneBits = bv.rankThird(bv.getNumberOfSupportedBits());
        
        for (int i = 0; i < bv.getNumberOfSupportedBits(); i++) {
            int actualRank = referenceBv.rank(i);
            int rank1 = bv.rankFirst(i);
            int rank2 = bv.rankSecond(i);
            int rank3 = bv.rankThird(i);
            
            int selectIndex = random.nextInt(numberOfOneBits) + 1;
            int actualSelect = referenceBv.select(selectIndex);
            int select1 = bv.selectFirst(selectIndex);
            
            if (select1 != actualSelect) {
                System.out.printf(
                        "ERROR: i = %d, actualSelect = %d, select1 = %d.\n",
                        i,
                        actualSelect,
                        select1);
            }

            if (rank3 != actualRank) {
                System.out.printf(
                        "ERROR: i = %d, actual rank = %d, rank1 = %d, " + 
                        "rank2 = %d, rank3 = %d.\n",
                                  i,
                                  actualRank,
                                  rank1,
                                  rank2,
                                  rank3);
            }
            
            assertEquals(actualRank, rank1);
            assertEquals(actualRank, rank2);
            assertEquals(actualRank, rank3);
            assertEquals(actualSelect, select1);
        }
    }
    
    private static RankSelectBitVector getRandomBitVector(Random random) {
        RankSelectBitVector bv = new RankSelectBitVector(5973);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < bv.getNumberOfSupportedBits(); i++) {
            if (random.nextDouble() < 0.3) {
                bv.writeBitOn(i);
            }
        }
        
        return bv;
    }
    
    private static BruteForceBitVector copy(RankSelectBitVector bv) {
        BruteForceBitVector referenceBv = 
                new BruteForceBitVector(bv.getNumberOfSupportedBits());
        
        for (int i = 0; i < bv.getNumberOfSupportedBits(); i++) {
            if (bv.readBit(i)) {
                referenceBv.writeBitOn(i);
            }
        }
        
        return referenceBv;
    }
    
    @Test
    public void toInteger() {
        RankSelectBitVector bitVector = new RankSelectBitVector(31);
        assertEquals(0, bitVector.toInteger(20));
        
        bitVector.writeBit(1, true);
        assertEquals(2, bitVector.toInteger(20));
        
        bitVector.writeBit(2, true);
        assertEquals(6, bitVector.toInteger(20));
        
        bitVector.writeBit(4, true);
        assertEquals(22, bitVector.toInteger(20));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void readWriteBit() {
        RankSelectBitVector bitVector = new RankSelectBitVector(30);
        bitVector.writeBit(12, true);
        assertTrue(bitVector.readBit(12));
        bitVector.writeBit(12, false);
        assertFalse(bitVector.readBit(12));
        assertFalse(bitVector.readBit(13));
    }
    
//    @Test
    public void bruteForceBitVectorSelect() {
        BruteForceBitVector bv = new BruteForceBitVector(8);
        
        bv.writeBitOn(2);
        bv.writeBitOn(4);
        bv.writeBitOn(6);
        bv.writeBitOn(7);
        
        assertEquals(2, bv.select(1));
        assertEquals(4, bv.select(2));
        assertEquals(6, bv.select(3));
        assertEquals(7, bv.select(4));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void countSetBits() {
        RankSelectBitVector bv = new RankSelectBitVector(11);
        
        assertEquals(0, bv.getNumberOfSetBits());
        
        bv.writeBitOn(10);
        
        assertEquals(1, bv.getNumberOfSetBits());
        
        bv.writeBitOn(5);
        
        assertEquals(2, bv.getNumberOfSetBits());
        
        bv.writeBitOff(10);
        
        assertEquals(1, bv.getNumberOfSetBits());
        
        bv.writeBitOff(5);
        
        assertEquals(0, bv.getNumberOfSetBits());
    }
}
```

(The missing class `BruteForceBitVector` is ***[here](https://github.com/coderodde/RankSelectBitVector.java/blob/main/src/test/java/com/github/coderodde/util/BruteForceBitVector.java)***.)

### Typical benchmark demo output

```
Seed = 1706175245835
Built the bit vector in 74 milliseconds.
Preprocessed the bit vector in 117 milliseconds.
--- Benchmarking rank operation ---
rankFirst() ran for 623 milliseconds.
rankSecond() ran for 110 milliseconds.
rankThird() ran for 625 milliseconds.
--- Benchmarking select operation ---
selectFirst() ran for 7593 milliseconds.
selectSecond() ran for 1399 milliseconds.
selectThird() ran for 6006 milliseconds.
```

## Critique request

I would like to hear about the following issues:

1. Efficiency. `rankThird(int)` in particular.
2. Unit tests. Did I cover all the possible corner cases?
3. Anything else?

Comment: `rankThird` doesn't look familiar to me. Where did you get that from? Actually this whole thing, which paper did you base this on? It's different from the rank/select techniques I know about.

Comment: I relied on the following book: http://www.genome-scale.info/

Comment: @harold https://rob-p.github.io/CMSC858D/static_files/presentations/CMSC858D-Lec08.pdf. Slide number 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Under this model you cannot do a bit-by-bit `extractBitVector` and preserve the desired time complexity. You should be able to extract a contiguous group of bits by masking out some bits and stitching together (a constant number of) parts (this would be cheaper if the backing storage was an array of words instead of bytes).

Going beyond that set of arithmetic operations, you can use `Long.bitCount` to efficiently count up to 64 bits (this should compile to either a `popcnt` instruction or at worst an `log bits`-step bithack if `popcnt` is not available, so it's not equivalent to looping over the bits). You can use that in `bruteForceRank`. You can also use `Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros` to compute an integer base-2 logarithm without a scary floating point logarithm.

Going even further beyond that set of operations, since Java 19 there is `Long.expand`, which you can use to implement the word-level `select` from [A Fast x86 Implementation of Select](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.00990) (it's not really x86-specific):

[image: algorithm PTSelect]

Transcribed into Java (not tested):

```
static int PTSelect(long x, int j) {
    long i = 1L << j;
    long p = Long.expand(i, x);
    return Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(p);
}
```

That would reduce the amount of recursion that the full `select` needs to do.

Comment: Very funky answer. I assume version 1.0.1 would be in order.